# How to get reading dotted quarter notes natural?

Tags: rhythm

I have difficulties with playing dotted quarter note followed by an eighth note. I try my hardest, but I just can't get it right. Any tips on improving?

Comment: Have you been counting **out loud**?

Comment: Tried it, but I guess my mind got distracted by it and I got lost even more

Comment: To me, counting isn't something you *try*, it's something you do and keep doing and practicing until you get better at it. And you have to start very slowly. One way to look at it is if you always do what you've always done, you'll always get what you've always gotten. In order to be able to do something you can't do, you usually have to start by doing something differently.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I would add "even if it seems more difficult at first," just to make that explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subdivide in 8ths. So it's a group of 3 followed by another 8th (3 + 1). Works with all crazy combinations I've seen: always go for the smallest common denominator (works for analyzing how to play multiple voices with different note combinations each at the same time).

Comment: Exactly.  Assuming you can think or clap a steady beat, this is the way to learn the sound of rhythms. _One_ two three _four one_ two three _four_ etc.